# How do I call DotNet Core API HealthCheck probes within Controller instead of setting up in Ctartup.cs

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, health-check

I would like to setup Microsoft.Extensions.Diagnostics.HealthChecks so that I can setup response body within controller instead of standard setup in Startup.cs.  Is this possible? If so, how can I achieve this?

The thought here is that I would like control over the response payload setter logic, and to do this within a controller action/method.

Online contains clear instructions on how to setup healthcheck probes, but all examples show the setup occuring within Startup.cs.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/health-checks?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Are probes strickly setup within startup only? Is this a constraint?

My understanding is that the healtcheck library is middleware that will terminate request from going further down the middleware pipeline, and that perhaps removing the middleware will mean that whatever was setup in startup must now be setup within controller action method.

Comment: A controller won't give you better control. For one thing, there are no views or even actions involved. The Health Check endpoint returns data based on its configuration.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, even though I may agree with you, the first thing to achieve is to see if this is even possible. If its impossible, thats value added to this post.

Comment: What is the actual question? What extra control do you want? You can control the route and payload already

Comment: The question is exactly this: Is it possible to setup healthcheck probes within controller action methods?

Comment: Because you want to do what? Controllers are a means to an end, not the end itself. Do you want to use POST? Multiple relative paths under the healtcheck URL? Receive input?

Comment: Because I want to setup healthcheck probes within controller actions methods. This is a constraint imposed and outside my control entirely. So what would be helpful hear to determining if this is possible, then if its impossible, that is ammunition.

Comment: You can't answer that question then without knowing *why*. The Health Check is a very specific service, it's not just routing. It may even use controllers internally. If you want a *different* kind of service, you can write a custom controller, the same way you'd write any controller

Comment: Someone answered below without knowing why. Thanks.

Comment: That's not a controller, that's the very same customization you didn't want to use. The answer actually shows that you *don't* need a controller's actions to begin with

Comment: What is the *actual* question here? How to enable/disable healtchecks through API calls perhaps? Or customize the healthcheck response? Heatlchecks themselves are services and middleware so they *can't* be configured in actions. They can be enabled or disabled though. As for changing the response format while the application is still running - why? This will confuse monitoring tools that expected an `OK` or `Failed` response and now get a long JSON payload

Comment: Is the question how to provide a detailed healtcheck when needed? That's already possible without requiring runtime changes. It's possible to create *two* endpoints, one to publish the `OK/Failed` message needed by monitoring tools and one that provides the detailed check responses.

Answer (score 3):

*Is it possible to setup healthcheck probes within controller action methods?* Answer is **No**

You can use `app.UseHealthChecks` to have custom control on health check enpoint

```
app.UseHealthChecks("/health-detailed", new HealthCheckOptions
        {
            ResponseWriter = (context, result) =>
            {
                context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
                
                var json = new JObject(
                    new JProperty("status", result.Status.ToString()),
                    new JProperty("duration", result.TotalDuration),
                    new JProperty("results", new JObject(result.Entries.Select(pair =>
                        new JProperty(pair.Key, new JObject(
                            new JProperty("status", pair.Value.Status.ToString()),
                            new JProperty("tags", new JArray(pair.Value.Tags)),
                            new JProperty("description", pair.Value.Description),
                            new JProperty("duration", pair.Value.Duration),
                            new JProperty("data", new JObject(pair.Value.Data.Select(
                                p => new JProperty(p.Key, p.Value))))))))));
                context.Response.ContentType = MediaTypeNames.Application.Json;
                return context.Response.WriteAsync(
                    json.ToString(Formatting.Indented));
            }
        });
```

Comment: We don't know what the OP wants the controller for. If it's for a UI, there are packages for that already. If it's to customize the output - there's no need for a controller in the first place

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: It would be useful if you included the package this person could use.  I would suggest leveraging https://github.com/Xabaril/AspNetCore.Diagnostics.HealthChecks

Answer (score 0):

TL&DR: Use this Library: https://github.com/Xabaril/AspNetCore.Diagnostics.HealthChecks if you want somthing already created.

This website provides a ton of fully functional healthchecks for different services such as PostGres, Redis, S3, and etc.

Comment: That's not what the OP asked, besides it's already linked to in the docs the question refers to. The OP wanted to *setup* the healthchecks in the controller action itself, not `Startup` or in .NET 6, in `Program`. The OP hasn't explained what the actual problem is yet. Perhaps they want to activate/deactivate checks through API calls? That's not what the question asks though, and wouldn't be done by setting the healtchecks up in actions anyway